# Is there any way to know that the kafka topic got created using java

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have two different service - **config-service** & **data-populator-service**. **config-service** responsibility is to create the topic and **data-populator-service** push the data to the kafka service. Please note that **config-service** & **data-populator-service** are isolated one.

My question -  is there any better way for the **data-populator-service** to know that the topic got created?

Currently I am using

```
_Collection<TopicListing> topicListings = adminClient.listTopics().listings().get();_
```

and check for my topic in the *topicListings* periodically. Is there any callback mechanism?

Please note that I am using *org.apache.kafka* for my producer.

Comment: @Deadpool It should not be a duplicate question as my question is related to callback mechanism after a topic got created

Comment: once topic is existed? then why do you want to check periodically?

Comment: I have two different services (k8s) - config-service & data-populator-service. config-service is responsible for creating topic and data-populator-service publishes data to the topic if it is exist, otherwise it should not push the data. So, data-populator-service needs to check if the topic is got created so that it can push the data